# How can I group and count by most frequent values in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

Having a scheme like this

```
[{
id:1, category:['gourmet','mexican','breakfasts'], food:'eggs&Beans'
},
{
id:2, category:['breakfasts'], food:'waffles'
},
{
id:3, category:['mexican','breakfasts'], food:'burrito'
},]
```

How could I group and count categories with most frequent value to achieve something like this:

```
[
{category: 'breakfasts', count:3, foods:['eggs&beans','waffles','burrito']},
{category: 'mexican', count:2, foods:['eggs&beans','burrito']},
{category: 'gourmet', count:1, foods:['eggs&beans']},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/jYUjXUtzvru

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$category" }, //  break into individual documents
  {
    $group: { // group by category
      _id: "$category",
      count: { $sum: 1 }, // get the count
      foods: { $push: "$food" } // add food the array
    }
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } }, // sort by count
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      category: "$_id",
      foods: 1,
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```